# Using Case to create a node when using Load CSV

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher

I am trying to create two different nodes and relationships based on certain data in a CSV.

I want to be able to create a Node like seen in the script below. Where if "AGGREGATE" is in a specific column then create a Node based off a different column.

If "AGGREGATE" is not in that column then do not create a node.

```
:auto USING PERIODIC COMMIT 5000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///TestFull.csv' AS test

WITH test WHERE test.equip_id IS NOT NULL
WITH test, SPLIT(test.equip_id, '/') as eid,
(CASE test.path_bandwidth
WHEN 'AGGREGATE' THEN test.path_leg_name
END) as agg
MERGE (logip:LogiP {logiKey: eid[0] + '.' + agg})
```

> Getting the error:   **"Cannot merge node using null property values for
>   logiKey"**

If I change the *NOT NULL* statement to `test.path_leg_name` or `path_bandwidth`, I get the same error as well. I do not see any place there there could be a null value. If I remove the NOT NULL line then I still get the same error too.

Any suggestions how I can make this happen?

After I get this to work, I then need to make a relationship based off this.

```
(p:Port) - [:SUB_EQUIP] -> (l:LogiP)
```

if the LogiP was not created from the last statement then it automatically creates this relationship instead:

```
(p:Port) - [:SUB_EQUIP] -> (s:SubPort)
```

I haven't been able to find anything to help me with that part.

All suggestions help!

Comment: Is that your actual query? `granite` is not defined, so you should get a different error.

Comment: granite was a typo in that instance.. it actually is test and not granite

Comment: By the way, you have not provided enough info for the `Port` follow-on questions. In any case, different issues belong in different SO Questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an `ELSE` condition in your `CASE` statement when the value isn't 'AGGREGATE', it returns NULL for `agg`.

```
(CASE granite.path_bandwidth
    WHEN 'AGGREGATE' THEN granite.path_leg_name
    ELSE ''
END) as agg
```

That will fix there error, but it will create the node still but with the value being `eid[0] + '.'`.  To only create nodes for "AGGREGATE", try adding a `WHERE` statement

```
(CASE granite.path_bandwidth
    WHEN 'AGGREGATE' THEN granite.path_leg_name
END) as agg
WHERE agg IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This worked but now I actually also need to split 'agg' as well with '/' as the splitDelimiter and I am unsure how to make that happen?

Comment: I think the response from @cybersam should answer this, but if not, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to use a `CASE` expression:

```
:auto USING PERIODIC COMMIT 5000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///TestFull.csv' AS test
WITH test
WHERE EXISTS(test.equip_id) AND test.path_bandwidth = 'AGGREGATE'
MERGE (logip:LogiP {logiKey: SPLIT(test.equip_id, '/')[0] + '.' + test.path_leg_name})
```

Also, if you need to split the `path_leg_name` and `equip_id` in the same way:

```
:auto USING PERIODIC COMMIT 5000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///TestFull.csv' AS test
WITH test
WHERE EXISTS(test.equip_id) AND test.path_bandwidth = 'AGGREGATE'
MERGE (logip:LogiP {logiKey: SPLIT(test.equip_id, '/')[0] + '.' + SPLIT(test.path_leg_name, '/')[0]})
```